# How to write a method signature "T that implements Comparable<T>" in Java?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

What signature should I have on my `insert`-method? I'm struggling with the generics. In a way, I want both `Comparable<T>` and `T` and I have tried with `<Comparable<T> extends T>`.

```
public class Node<T> {

    private Comparable<T> value;

    public Node(Comparable<T> val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    // WRONG signature - compareTo need an argument of type T
    public void insert(Comparable<T> val) {
        if(value.compareTo(val) > 0) {
            new Node<T>(val);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i4 = new Integer(4);
        Integer i7 = new Integer(7);

        Node<Integer> n4 = new Node<>(i4);
        n4.insert(i7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to compare 2 `Comparator`'s?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman I want to compare two `Comparable` so I can get them in an order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but should you not include that in the declaration of the class?

```
public static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> { //HERE

    private T value;

    public Node(T val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public void insert(T val) {
        if (value.compareTo(val) > 0) {
            new Node<T>(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: it is good practice to use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` instead of `<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`